# If statement with a variable and no expression

Tags: java, if-statement, expression

I came across these `if` statements while watching a Java pong game tutorial video:

```
boolean upAccel, downAccel;
double y, velY;

public HumanPaddle() {
   upAccel = false; downAccel = false;
}

public void setUpAccel(boolean input) {
   upAccel = input;
}
public void setDownAccel(boolean input) {
   downAccel = input;
}

// moves the paddle
public void move() {

   /* What does the 'if(upAccel){ }' expression do..? */
   if(upAccel) {
      velY -= 1; 
   }
   if(downAccel) {
      velY += 1;
   }
   y = y + velY;
}
```

So I understand that the `setUpAccel` and `setDownAccel` methods accept a boolean `input` which can either be true or false. However, I experimented with the `if` statements - and changed `if(upAccel)` to `if(upAccel = true)`. Java didn't see the expression as the same thing, so I realized that the two expressions were different!

My question is, what does the `if(upAccel)` expression test out?

Comment: `if (x == true)` is equivalent to `if (x)` when `x` is a boolean.

Comment: If statements evaluate a boolean expression. Boolean variables can be used as boolean expressions.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison. So `if (upAccel = true)...` is the equivalent of `upAccel = true; if (upAccel)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* What does the 'if(upAccel){ }' expression do..? */
   if(upAccel) {
      velY -= 1; 
   }
```

it will evaluate to true can be rewritten as

```
/* What does the 'if(upAccel){ }' expression do..? */
   if(upAccel==true) {
      velY -= 1; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `(upAccel)` checks if the condition is true then it continues to perform `velY -=1`.
`(upAccel)` is the same as `(upAccel == true)`.
The same goes with downAccel.

Comment: My bad, I was using one equal sign - which is used to ASSIGN variables, not set them. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck.